# " " Does not exist in current context?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Im making a website that sends information to a mysql server, using asp.net. code. The problem Im having is that when i debug the code and launch the page, I get these error:

[image]

Im not sure why, I have this error.
Here is my code:

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"                 AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default"%>  
      <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table width="300px" >
    <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td >Last Name</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Email Address</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
    </asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string cnnString = "Server=localhost;Port=1111;Database=ci_series;Uid=asdfasdf;Pwd=*******";


        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);


        string cmdText = "INSERT INTO membership (first_name ,last_name ,username ,password ,";
        cmdText += "email_address)VALUES (first_name ,last_name ,username ,password ,email_address);";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connection);


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?first_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?last_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?email_address", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;

        connection.Open();

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        lblError.Text = "Data Saved";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
    }
```

How Do i Fix this? What does "Not exist in the current context" mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `</asp:Content>` instead `</asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">`

Comment: Ok that worked, but now I have this error: `Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.`

Comment: This is a content page, your master page already has the `form`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Make sure runat="server" is on the html tag on your master page.

2) Sometimes you get this error due to and assembly caching problem because VS gets confused about what actually needs to be recompiled. -- I just delete the cache items and recompile normally, figuring that more than 1 thing may be wrong

Comment: Yes the runat="server" was the error. I cannot post my solutions until I get 10 rep, but that was the fix to my second error. Thank you!!

Comment: Be sure to fix the other problems too -- the extra <form> tag will cause problems too

Comment: Also, VS is usually not just confused at random, it is because another (often an unused copy) page has the same classname, so VS does not recompile the one you need. See, wiping the cache and recompiling is not really "the solution", but it saves you time to of digging out the duplicate so you can focus on what you are doing at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when getting old VS2005 aspx/aspx.cs files into a new project in VS2013. I resolved this by creating a new web application, creating a new webform for each aspx page and copying the code for .aspx and .cs. Once copied I have to change the .cs files first line to use **CodeBehind instead of CodeFile** .

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Login" %>
```

TO

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Login" %>
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: If you have old master page or page , creating new page and copying the content will resolve the issue ....

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 issues

1. `</asp:Content> instead </asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">` . It's already put the comment from piLHa
2. You don't need  `form tag`in content page . the `form tag` was already defined in `master page` , so please remove the `form tag` in your content page.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem when i was coding with c# aspx and i figured out this like that:

I had deleted this **Inherits="*project_name.ClassName*"** from my XXX.aspx file mistakenly which is first line in my XXX.aspx file.. And then when i added **Inherits="*project_name.ClassName*"** this code to my XXX.aspx first line to my file and then it solved my problem. You should make control your first line in your XXX.aspx file, you could delete **Inherits="*project_name.ClassName*"** wrongly....

I hope you will figure out the problem for this answer.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code of .aspx page in @page tag

Replace this: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.Test" %>

Replace with: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/Test.aspx.cs" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.Test" %>

Answer (score -1):

Right_click on "WebApplication"

[image]

and Click on "Convert to Web Application "
[image]